# dajaxice implementation neither giving any error nor working

Tags: python, django, formwizard, dajaxice

I am using Dajaxice in formwizard and is in a very confused condition, because neither it shows any error nor it shows output. My code is below:

ajax.py

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def sayhello(request):
   return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello World'})
```

urls.py

```
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
dajaxice_autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),)
```

wizard1.html

```
{% block head %}
{% dajaxice_js_import %}
<title>My base template</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function my_callback(data){alert(data.message);alert("Hello");}
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<input type="button" onclick="Dajaxice.trusform.dajaxice.core.sayhello(my_callback)" value="Get message from server!">
{% endblock %}
```

Django Project

```
trustform
  manage.py
  trustform
    ajax.py
    forms.py
    urls.py
    settings.py
  dajaxice
    dajaxice.core.js
  templates
    wizard1.html
```

Could you please particularly advice about path structure, specifically in onclick methods, because I suspect it is due to wrong paths but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Dajaxice.trusform.dajaxice.core.sayhello
```

with

```
Dajaxice.trustform.sayhello
```

since the `sayhello` method is part of your app. Also, you're missing the "t" in "trustform" so add that too.